# rails pretty routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, pretty-urls

I have news conroller where news select by year. 
in routes.rb I have

```
  get 'news' => 'pages#news'
  get 'news/:year' =>'pages#news'
```

url `http://localhost:3000/news/2012` is ok but when I try to create link, it's no pretty.

 for example: `= link_to year, news_path(year: 2012)`
I see `http://localhost:3000/news?year=2012` instead `http://localhost:3000/news/2012`

How I can fix it?
 p.s. item it's model for news controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace with one line:

```
get 'news/(:year)' =>'pages#news'
```

Explanations:

Router rule is: first match first served. `get 'news'` matches your path so it adds `year` as a query param.

Alternate solution would be to switch your lines but it's better to keep only one.